# Is the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x$ for $x \leq 0$ and $x+1$ for $x>0$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x$ for $x \leq 0$ and $x+1$ for $x>0$ continuous at $x = 0$?

If we consider the limit definition, then $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = 1$ while $\lim_{x \to 0-} f(x) = 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

1. Is $f(0) = 0$ a necessity for continuity?
2. How do I contradict the continuity of $f$ at $0$ using the epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: For continuity, the limit must exist at $x=0$ and it must be $f(0)$. In this case, the limit does not exist. Note however that the limit from the right is not $2$ but $1$.

Comment: Wait yes, I meant $1$. Edited! @Swike Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer $(1)$, for continuity at $x=0$, first the limit needs to exist at $x=0$, i.e. the left and right hand limits need to be equal, which it is not. If that condition holds, only then you check if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=f(0)$$, because you first need to ensure that the above LHS actually exists. And yes, the above condition is necessary to check continuity at $0$.

For $(2)$, let's remind ourselves of the epsilon-delta definition for continuity, which is "$f(x)$ is said to be continuous at $x=c$" if $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta_{\epsilon,c} >0 \text{ such that } \mid x-c \mid < \delta_{\epsilon,c} \implies \mid f(x)-f(c)\mid <\epsilon$$ (The subscripts $\epsilon,c$ denote that the choice of $\delta$ usually depends on the values of $\epsilon$ and $c$.)

For our $f(x)$, it is enough to show that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that there is no $\delta$ for it such that the above condition holds.

Choose $\epsilon=0.0001$, we have $c=0$, where we want to check continuity, suppose $\exists \delta>0$ such that the condition mentioned above, holds.

Then for $\mid x\mid < \delta$ we should have $$\mid f(x)-f(0)\mid <0.0001 (*)$$

However, $x=\dfrac{\delta}2>0$ satisfies $\mid x\mid < \delta$, but $$\mid f\left( \dfrac{\delta}2 \right) - 0 \mid = \dfrac{\delta}2+1>0.0001 \text{ violates } (*)$$

So there doesn't exist any choice of $\delta>0$, which proves the discontinuity.